# How to revert back to listening state with a multithreaded server in C++ when client disconnects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, client-server

I want to be able to create a server that continually listens and accepts clients. Currently, my server is able to accept clients and when the clients naturally terminate (stop sending messages), the server can continue to listen for messages. However, if the client terminates prematurely (exiting the client program), then the server either continually prints out error messages (failure to send message) or if I include the break statement, terminates.

Can someone explain why this is and how to have the second scenario emulate the behavior in the first scenario? Apologies in advance for the poor formatting, and if any clarification/elaboration is necessary, please ask.

```
start = listen(_listener, SOMAXCONN);

/* Create the thread */
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);
    while (true)
    {
        _messager = accept(_listener, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
        printTime();
        if (_messager != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Client Connection success!" << endl;
            std::thread newThread(exchange, (LPVOID)_messager);
            cout << "Thread ID: " << newThread.get_id() << endl;
            newThread.detach();
        }
        /*else
        {
            break;
        }*/
    }

DWORD WINAPI exchange(LPVOID param)
{
    SOCKET messager = (SOCKET)param;
    while (true)
    {
        int bytesReceived = receiveMessage(messager);
        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            closesocket(messager);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (bytesReceived > 0)
        {
            int bytesSent = sendMessage(messager, _msg1);
            if (bytesSent == -1)
            {
                closesocket(messager);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error on receive from socket " << messager << endl;
            closesocket(messager);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `_messager == SOCKET_ERROR` you simply have to continue the loop. If you break you get out of the loop and terminate the program.

```
        if (_messager != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Client Connection success!" << endl;
            std::thread newThread(exchange, (LPVOID)_messager);
            cout << "Thread ID: " << newThread.get_id() << endl;
            newThread.detach();
        }
```